# Need counter-examples to disprove "mean independence implies variance independence" and " variance independence implies mean independence"

Tags: probability, independence

Define variance independence as $Var(Y|X=x)=Var(Y)$ and $Var(X|Y=y)=Var(X)$ for any $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R$.

How can I construct counter-examples to disprove "mean independence implies variance independence" and " variance independence implies mean independence"?

I'm thinking of $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=2X\sim N(0,4)$, but not sure if this works.

Comment: Well did you even try to see if, say, $Var(Y|X=x)=Var(X)$ held true for your example? If so, what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with multiplication, addition and 3 fair coin flips. I'll call the random variables for the flips $F_1$, $F_2$ and $F_3$, and their values are either $-1$ or $1$.

...sure you don't want to try it by yourself? Ok, here we go:

$X=F_1 + F_2$

$Y=F_3(F_1 + F_2)$

and

$X = F_1 + F_2$,

$Y = F_2 + F_3$